Flexible conduit for electrical wiring to "future-proof" runs in a wall
I have a very big and urgent project coming up on which one exterior wall of my 2 story house will be gutted to the studs, new windows, insulation, stucco.
Now I do not have enough time to think of all my "dream projects", where I would want lamps, switches, receptacles, apart from the ones already existing.
In Europe, it is very common to use PVC conduit (similar to smurf tubes) embedded in brick/mortar and run THHN-like wiring. Since walls are much more complex than just drywood, it is also common to run empty of such tubes and empty electrical boxes, should they be needed in the future. Wires can be easily pulled then.
Since this is an exterior wall which is now open anyway, I would like to have some empty tubing as well. There will be insulation, so simple cable pulling isn't possible as it is for interior empty stud bays.
Low voltage (like Ethernet) is pretty trivial: I will just get a roll of smurf tube. Then my plan is to do two runs horizontal and vertical across the wall (one side terminating in the crawl space and/or attic) and take lots of pictures. If needed, I could cut open the wall exactly at the right spot and tap into the tube. Pulling wiring, be it CAT6, optical or whatever else may come it is easy then.
Line voltage is harder. I plan to run two 1" or 2" EMTs from crawl space to attic so I have a connection between these. But ideally I'd like to have some empty flexible tubing for other places on the wall as well. FMC is not really flexible. Smurf tubes are only listed for low voltage, I believe.
What would be the best solution to add future proofing for line voltage wiring in an exterior wall?

Most switches go near/beside door frames.  Most receptacles are about a foot from the floor in most rooms to about four feet in kitchens/bathrooms and so far away from each other(6ft?).  Any wall lamps will be the most difficult in placement, you almost need to know the placement now.

Honestly, not too worried for the internal inside stuff. But who knows what might come up in the future? Automated windows? A heater mounted on the wall outside? A different lamp outside? In these cases, I'd like to minimize the impact: I cut a small hole from the inside exactly where I know the conduit is. There I would cut it and put a box in between. Then either a blank cover on the inside and drilling outside, or directly an outside box and covering up inside.

You mention Europe, are you infact in Europe or is that just a mention?

@Jasen Just a mention. I am infact in California but originally from Europe (and a house there).

Electrical conduit must be terminated at a junction or pull box, whether there are wires inside or not;  there is no such thing as "tapping" into it later on. You are not going to be able to insert a box later on using only a "small" box-sized hole, and any such modification will require a new electrical permit and inspection. Electrical installations must conform to approved wiring methods and be complete in order to secure a permit and pass inspection.

ENT (smurf tube) is legit electrical conduit in a wall for line voltage. You can use it for low voltage as well, but that's not why it's made in the first place.
Unless you have weird local rules other than NEC, that should cover you.
https://carlonsales.com/techinfo/brochures/electrical/ENT_2B43.pdf
States on page 14:

Electrical Nonmetallic Tubing (ENT), is designed to replace EMT, flexible metal conduit or other raceway or cable systems, for installation in accordance with Article 362 of the National Electrical Code, other applicable sections of the Code, and local codes.

On page 3 it notes that the (smurfy) blue color is their registered trademark.
For installation in concrete they mention trying to keep it straight where it does not need to bend by frequently tying it, to avoid making many small bends that end up causing it to be difficult to install wires. The same philosophy should probably be adhered to inside a stud wall, for the same reason. 360 degrees of bend between pulling points applies to flexible conduit as well as non-flexible conduit.
